# Open current tab's address to modify/edit/change it with pentadactyl

Tags: pentadactyl

I'm using Pentadactyl and looking for a way to modify the current tab's address, but I haven't found anything yet. Is there any command to open current tab's address to modify it? Any other workaround is fine also.

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can open current tabs address with the keystroke **"y"** in **normal mode**. This is called Yanking. It copies the current url into the clipboard and will be shown as an echo.

2. If you want the url to be in console you can press key capital o ("O"). This will open the current url in the console to be edited.

Comment: Great answer. Now if only I could use vim keystrokes to edit the URL after pressing O ;-).

Comment: @AaronMahan You can press Ctrl+T while in the command-line to enter Text Edit mode or press Ctrl+I to edit it in an external editor.

Comment: @Alraxite Thanks! Ctrl+T good, Ctrl+I better. Ctrl+T on the command line is extremely limited (missing $, 2-stroke motion commands such as ge, and probably more that I haven't tested).

Comment: Documentation for which mappings are currently supported in text edit mode: http://5digits.org/help/pentadactyl/index.xhtml#t-map-index